# Creating Visual Displays of Calculations and Solutions

Tags: education

In the late 80s or 90s, I remember watching video online of a series of lectures in a college physics course at UCAL. One of the sponsors was the Annenberg Foundation. Most of the time the video was shots in the lecture hall, but there were also cutaways to an empty black space in which an equation or calculation would appear and as the voiceover articulated the operations necessary to solve the original equation it would change in time to reflect the effects of each step; one could watch as numbers, variables, signs were struck through, faded in or out, moved around, etc.; thus, “showing your work” was being done fluidly in time instead of frozen in space the way it would be if one were doing the math on paper.

So, to my questions: 1. Does anybody know the video I’m talking about and where to find it? (I've been looking on and off for years and never have); 2. Does anybody understand what I’ve tried to describe going on in the cutaways and what I need to make my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

Could it be "The Mechanical Universe" series? See [here](https://youtu.be/szCChCc58dg?t=19m5s) for an example of the kind of manipulations used in the series. Sponsored by Annenberg, but produced by Caltech, not UCLA.

Comment: Bingo! That's it. Thank you. How they're made still eludes me. It doesn't resemble Flash animation, if it indeed even could've been given when these videos were produced. But I'm very glad to be one step closer so, again, thank you.